# Why CKEditor does not care about compatibility?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, compatibility, versioning, ckeditor5

I implemented CKEditor on a project and I was surprised to discover, either in the interface or in the source code, that it's written in ECMA 6, using all its modern features such as the short function notation ([arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)).

Given these features are not widely supported as the ECMA 5 version is (not yet as of today, July 2018), I ask why the developers made this strategic choice: are they not interested in a wide browser compatibility? Or is CKEditor so well spread to allow them to dictate a precise direction towards modern browser versions, risking to lose a portion of users?

Comment: https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/advanced-setup.html#option-building-to-es5-target

Answer (score 4):

### Browsers are not a problem

Let's be clear here:

**CKEditor 5 can be run in all browsers which it supports without any transpilation**. All browsers which it supports have a sufficient level of ES6 support.

### Why would you need ES5?

The only reason why you might want to transpile CKEditor 5 from ES6 to ES5 are:

- Legacy browsers which it doesn't support (at least at the moment).
- Existing setups which use ES6-incompatible JS minifiers (UglifyJS). It may be a bit inconvenient to include CKEditor 5 in such applications but, as it was commented already, we [explain how to transpile CKEditor 5 to ES5](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/advanced-setup.html#option-building-to-es5-target).
- Development environments for frameworks like React (`create-react-app`) or Angular (`angular-cli`) which didn't catch up yet and still require that libs kept in your `node_modules/` are in ES5.

The last case is indeed a bigger problem because you don't have that much control over this environments as on your own projects. As [I commented on Twitter](https://twitter.com/reinmarpl/status/996395908811182080):

> 3 years ago we decided that CKEditor 5 will be released in ES6 because all browsers which we planned to support should have a sufficient ES6 support by our ETA.
>
> We were right – it worked great... in the browsers.
>
> It turned out that the problem is in the build environments (create-react-app, angular-cli) which did not catch up.
>
> We'll need to introduce ES5 builds just to satisfy these envs ;/
>
> To clarify – I'm not criticising authors of these tools. It's more of an observation that we've been always worried about browser support while today the tools stop us.
>
> And, as I mentioned in the other tweet, the problem is broad (e.g. finding a supported, stable, ES6+ compatible and fast minifier – see e.g. https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/issues/262 …).

Fortunately, the situation is improving:

[@mtrebizan](https://twitter.com/mtrebizan/status/996481323563913216):

> I think CRA 2.0 will be shipping non-transpiled code,just don't know how far release is. cc @dan_abramov

[@dan_abramov](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/996488923844169729):

> There’s alphas you can try. Other than that the ETA is when the community makes it happen  there’s active work and you can help too

I know there was work in angular-cli on improving this situation too. So, in a relatively short time, all should work smoothly too.

### Time aspect

The difference (in terms of features) between ES6 and ES5 is huge. Back in 2014, when we've been starting CKEditor 5 development, we chose ES5. ES6 wasn't standardised yet.

However, the situation changed in 2015. ES6 got published and our tests proved that all features we looked to (classes, generators, iterators, weak sets, weak maps, and more) were already available in Chrome. We decided to go for it and see.

About 1.5 year later CKEditor 5 worked natively (without any transpilation) in all modern browsers (with the exception of Safari which had a nasty bug). At the same time, [`babel-minify`](https://github.com/babel/minify) became usable so we didn't have to transpile CKEditor 5 to ES5 even for production.

It's 2018 and the number of obstacles was reduced even more. There's a chance that still this year you won't have to transpile CKEditor 5 to ES5 unless your project is supposed to be ES5 because of browser support (but then, why would you include CKEditor 5? it's not going to work in those browsers anyway).

Looking at the history of CKEditor 3-4, CKEditor 5 will stay with us for the next 8+ years. So, we're talking here about 2026+. This means that for the vast majority of its lifetime ES6 will not be a problem.

Answer (score 3):

CKEditor supports vanilla javascript (ES5) and ES6 as well. The issue is not the editor, it just supports it, doesn't care about compatibility because it doesn't know where your code is going to run but only how to highlight and give you tools to develop it.

The thing is that, by the time, the ECMA standard is under heavy development, improving in every version, so there's a lot going on, there are a lot of proposals being added every month, some passes and makes their way into the standard, which later gets into cool features we can use like arrow function.

All of that makes it harder for browsers to catch on the [new updates](http://es6-features.org). Even so, there are a lot that [supports the new features now](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6) (you may track the updates in that page).

Anyway, besides from all of that, you may use a code compiler like [Babel](https://babeljs.io) (which compiles ES6/ES7... down to code the browsers can understand such as ES5). It's widely adopted, and recommended for the thing it does: Make your life easier. Many big companies adopted it, such as Facebook which uses react (and made it) using Babel to compile not only ES6 but JSX ([check this](https://reactjs.org/jsx-compiler.html)).

> Side note: **Why should I use ES6 if I need a compiler?**
>
> https://itnext.io/why-you-should-use-es6-56bd12f7ae09

Comment: You wrote _"it doesn't know where your code is going to run"_: any client-side application may check for the platform it is running on, or, which is better, for the features it exposes. Moreover, when you say _"(it knows) only how to highlight and give you tools to develop it"_ I am not sure we are referring to the same argument: CKEditor is a WYSIWYG editor, not a syntax highlighter. Then: _"All of that makes it harder for browsers to catch on the new updates"_ that's my point, in fact browser compatibility is a good feature of a solid web app just because of it.

Comment: What could help me in understanding your point is compiling: _"Anyway, besides from all of that, you may use a code compiler like Babel (which compiles ES6/ES7... down to code the browsers can understand such as ES5)"_: ok, but the source code published is ES6, the quickstart guide advices on how to use it, not how to compile it down to more supported versions, or maybe I missed it.